# Example of a Frobenius algebra that is not projective over a Frobenius subalgebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, projective-modules, frobenius-algebras

I'd like to know an example of a Frobenius algebra $A$, with a subalgebra $B$ that is itself a Frobenius algebra, such that $A$ is not projective as a left $B$-module.  I don't require any compatibility between the Frobenius algebra structures (e.g. trace map) of $A$ and $B$.  In all the examples I know of (group algebras of symmetric groups, nilcoxeter algebras, Hecke algebras of type A, etc.), $A$ is even a free $B$-module.  But I don't see any reason, a priori, for this to always be the case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can take $A={\mathbb C}[x]/x^3$ and $B$ -- subalgebra generated by $x^2$.